# Is it possible to toggle debug mode for i18next dynamically?

Tags: logging, i18next

Currently I have this setup on an app that employs [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next)

```js
const i18nextOptions =  {
   debug: true
   // more options
}

// initialization of i18next
window.i18next.init(i18nextOptions, () => {
    i18next.logger.setDebug(true) // doesn't changes anything
    i18next.translator.logger.setDebug(true) // this makes to start logging something...
})
```

The thing is **I'm not sure how to turn the debug ON after the init phase finishes**

TL;DR

As far I see the source code [there is a `baseLogger`](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/master/i18next.js#LL213C3-L213C33) and is used to create other logger for specific "components" of i18next, using `baseLogger.create(<component>)` where `<component>` can be any of these values `{"translator", "languageUtils", "interpolator", "formatter", "pluralResolver", "backendConnector"}`

I guess the idea is to have "modular" loggers, and you can switch on or off accordingly to any needs. The thing is, I didn't find any documentation about it and how to handle logging dynamically.

Comment: This affair [continues on github](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1954)